# How to exclude arguments passed from command prompt argc argv in C?

Tags: c, function, parameters, argv, argc

I need to add fractions given by the user through command prompt in the format

```
a/b b/c
```

I thought I could do it this way:

```
n1 = atoi(argv[1]);
d1 = atoi(argv[3]);
n2 = atoi(argv[4]);
d2 = atoi(argv[6]);
```

Thereby skipping the slashes, but this just crashes the program. Is there some way to skip over certain characters passed as arguments through command prompt? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332212/reading-fractions-in-c

Comment: OT: if `0` is part of the set of numbers you want to have converted then `atoi()` isn't usable as it returns `0` on error. Use `strtol()` instead then.

Answer (score 3):

If the user writes:

```
add_fractions 1/2 2/3
```

then your program is given just 3 arguments:

```
argv[0] = "add_fractions"
argv[1] = "1/2"
argv[2] = "2/3"
argv[3] = 0
```

and `argc` is 3.

You would have to do something like this (after checking that you were given 2 arguments):

```
char *ptr;
n1 = atoi(argv[1]);
if ((ptr = strchr(argv[1], '/') != 0)
    d1 = atoi(ptr+1);
else
    d1 = 1;
n2 = atoi(argv[2]);
if ((ptr = strchr(argv[2], '/') != 0)
    d2 = atoi(ptr+1);
else
    d2 = 1;
```

Or you could pack the repeated sequence of statements into a function (with a slightly different twist in the logic):

```
void read_fraction(char const *str, int *num, int *den)
{
    char *ptr;
    *num = atoi(str);
    if ((ptr = strchr(str, '/') == 0)
        ptr = "/1";
    *den = atoi(ptr+1);
}
```

and in `main()`:

```
read_fraction(argv[1], &n1, &d1);
read_fraction(argv[2], &n2, &d2);
```

You might want to think about validation; the numerator becomes 0 if there isn't a number as the first part of the string, but the denominator becomes 0 if there is a slash and there isn't a number after the slash, which might not be exactly what you want.  One fix is to set the denominator to 1 if the value from `atoi(ptr+1)` is 0.  It's a cop-out, but prevents rampant crashes.  Or you could use another completely different implementation in the body of the function:

```
int read_fraction(char const *str, int *num, int *den)
{
    if (sscanf(str, "%d/%d", num, den) != 2)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

And then check in `main()`:

```
if (read_fraction(argv[1], &n1, &d1) == 0 &&
    read_fraction(argv[2], &n2, &d2) == 0)
    ...process valid fractions...
else
    ...make appropriate comments about how to use the program...
```

Using a function is 'better' from several points of view.  In [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragprog.com/book/tpp/the-pragmatic-programmer), it is called the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Kernighan and Plauger summarized it neatly in their book [The Elements of Programming Style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070342075):

- The subroutine call permits us to summarize the irregularities in the argument list, where we can see quickly what is going on.
- The subroutine itself summarizes the regularities of the code, so repeated patterns need not be used.

Comment: +1 but can you please explain what you mean by the alternative _pack the sequence into a function_.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Shouldn't it be "_unpack_ the sequence in the function"?

Comment: I mean 'pack the repeated sequence of _N_ statements into a function', so the correct verb is 'pack' (writing the code out twice inline as in the original would be unpacking it).  If you consider it to be 'unpack the argument string in a function', then 'unpack' becomes the correct verb.

Comment: The former is about code and the latter is about data; got it now, thanks! :)

Comment: Use `%d/%d%c` with `sscanf` and check that the result is 2; that ensures there's no _following_ junk in the value…

Answer (score 2):

> a/b b/c

It just creates 2 entries in the argument list, one is `a/b` and another is `b/c`.

So, `argv[0]`, `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are valid and `argc` is `3`.

Spaces are important to separate arguments (unless you wrap a entry inside `""`)