# adding fractions given as arguments C

Tags: c, arguments, fractions

**My assignment states**
"The program is not allowed to show any menu: It must receive the option of the mathematical function to execute and its arguments as parameters in the main function."
and examples of execution of the program are (suppose the program is called c2):

```
./c2 fradd 2/3 5/7 
# Expected output: 29/21
```

My understanding is that we have to write a function `fFradd()` outside of `int main (int argc, char * argv[])`.  Then implement that function.

**So my question is**: How do I take the fractions given as arguments and split them into `n1`, `d1`, `n2`, `d2`?

I know (using the example given) that 2/3 would be saved into one space of the `argv[]` array (I'm not sure that's the proper terminology but hopefully you understand my point). I'm just not sure how to get the program to read that argument (`argv[2]`) and recognize 2/3 as `n1`/`d1`.

The closest I could find was using something like `sscanf(argv[2],"%i/%i",n1,d1);`, but I know `sscanf` is for strings...and obviously that can't be done with `scanf()`

Comment: What is wrong with using `sscanf(argv[2],"%i/%i",&n1,&d1);`? (Note that you'll need the `&`s if you want to assign to `int`s).

Comment: "... but I know sscanf is for strings..." The you need to study more. Its for pulling formatted typed-data from a string buffer, putting it at specified memory addresses. You're close though. Change the two parameters to `&n1, &d1)`, then [read the `sscanf()` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for why.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923006/how-to-exclude-arguments-passed-from-command-prompt-argc-argv-in-c/19923104#19923104)

Answer (score 0):

You're 100% right, you should use `sscanf()`.

Not sure what you mean by "`sscanf()` is for strings". It's for *scanning* a string, and converting parts of the string into other values of other types. Here, [read the manual page one more time](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to refresh your idea of what the function is capable of doing.

Converting to integer is very common, and is done almost as you said. You must pass the *address* of the destination variable for each conversion though, so make it:

```
int n, d,

if(sscanf(argv[i], "%d/%d", &n, &d) == 2)
{
  printf("got the fraction %d/%d\n", n, d);
}
```

the above should probably be put into a loop, as the `argv[i]` implies.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. I guess I misunderstood when it was first explained. Thank you so much!